# How to get a javascript array that was created using ClientScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration back to the server?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to pass an array of data between JavaScript and code-behind C#. The data is retrieved from a central database and translated to an array on a page by [ClientScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration.aspx), where the user can edit it.

Now I want to post the data back to the database by code-behind code; but how do I access the modified array on the client-side page again? What's the reverse for `RegisterArrayDeclaration`, passing the data back from the client to the server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `RegisterArrayDeclaration` just renders the array in a javascript block. You will have to place the values of the (altered) array in a hidden field to get it back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Combine all array values into a comma-separated string and store that string into a HiddenField value in your client-side JavaScript code. After postback  read that hidden field value in server-side code and use String.Split method to get the array.

If you don't want to make a full postback - you can make an AJAX call, sending data in a POST request and reading it on the server via Request("name") method.

Comment: You have to somehow communicate with the server. Full Postback or AJAX callbacks are the ways. There're 3rd party libraries such as http://www.asp.net/signalr but in your case that would be an overkill